# Trying to save color from AmbilWarnaDialog with SharedPreferences it is not getting the color

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a dialog for `ColorPicker` which is added at `build.gradle`.
The dialog it is `AmbilWarnaDialog`.

I am able to change the color but the problem it is when I exit the app and again I open the color is the `colorPrimary` it is not getting the color from `SharedPreferences`.
I am able to save a color at the `SharedPreferences` but then it is not getting the color from there.

Below is my code.

`MainActivity.class`

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Change_Color, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int backcolorValue = sharedpreferences.getInt("back_color_code", 1);

    if (backcolorValue != 1) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: " + "e pera");
        changeHeader.setBackgroundColor(backcolorValue);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(backcolorValue);
    } else {
        changeHeader.setBackgroundColor(mDefaultColor);
    }


  public void openColorPicker() {

    AmbilWarnaDialog colorPicker = new AmbilWarnaDialog(this, mDefaultColor, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
            changeHeader.setBackgroundColor(color);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(color);

            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Change_Color, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("back_color_code", color);
            editor.apply();

            Log.d("TAG", "onOk: " + color);
        }
    });
    colorPicker.show();
}
```

`activity_main.XML`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/ActivityMain">
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutTitle"
        style="@style/RelativeLayoutTitleSearch">
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout/
```

`styles.xml`

```
 <style name="RelativeLayoutTitleSearch">
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue_title</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/title_height</item>
        <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    </style>
```

The `color` at the `Dialog` return a number something like `-112332`

Answer (score 0):

I have found where was the problem.
I have two times declared the `defaultColor` and it has take the non modified color.
I just have deleted one of them and it is working.